# What is the difference between worst hold slack and worst negative slack

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis

I have been looking all over google and I can't find a clear answer for what is the difference between worst hold slack and worst negative slack in the timing summary in vivado.  Right now I am building a integer divider and I am passing the worst negative slack but failing the worst hold slack.  What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worst negative slack is likely referring to setup times as opposed to hold times.

If you are failing hold timing, you should try to improve the setup slack (even if it is passing). Doing that will allow the fitter to basically make the routing delay longer to increase the hold times (at cost of setup time).